# How to bind a properties object to an existing element?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery you can create new elements and define properties on them in one step:

```
$("<div>", {title: "Hey there!", text: "I'm a DIV!"});
```

This produces:

```
<div title="Hey there!">I'm a DIV!</div>
```

Is there a way to do the same with an existing element? The following does not work:

```
$("#theDiv", {title: "Hey there!", text: "I'm a DIV!"});
```

Comment: `$( "#theDiv" ).attr({ title: "Hey there!" }).text( "I'm a DIV!" );` is not that bad...

Comment: @Šime Sure, but it's not what I want to do. :)

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. Don't you want to set the `title` attribute and the text-content of an existing DIV element?

Comment: Ah, you already have a props object and you want to use it? In that case maybe: `$( "#theDiv" ).attr( props ).text( props.text );`...

Comment: @Šime Yes. I *know* how I can set them manually. I explicitly don't want to. I want to pass in an object to some sort of function that then does the right thing, just exactly the same way I can do it when creating a fresh element (the fact that this works means that there *already is* a function that does the right thing).

Comment: @Šime I've found out how to do it, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out things are rather easy. jQuery uses `.attr()` for this.

```
$("#theDiv").attr({title: "Hey there!", text: "I'm a DIV!"}, true);
```

Note the second parameter set to `true`. This causes jQuery to use the same mechanism that it uses for freshly created elements.

Even function parameters work as expected:

```
$("#theDiv").attr({
    title: "Hey there!", 
    text: function () { return "some calculated value"; }
}, true);​
```

([See this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/v4fn5/))

Consequently, this will also work for event bindings, CSS modifications and all the other things jQuery can do:

```
$("#theDiv").attr({
    title: "Hi there", 
    text: function (i, v) { return v.replace(/not /, ""); },
    mouseover: function () { $(this).css({color: "red"}) },
    mouseout: function () { $(this).css({color: ""}) },
    css: { fontSize: "20pt", fontStyle: "italic" }
}, true);​
```

([See this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/v4fn5/1/))

This is **undocumented**, so it could change in any dot release without being listed in the release notes, but it seems *unlikely* to and it's easy to test it when upgrading jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I like that one, too. Thanks for the "undocumented" disclaimer. -- As far as I am concerned, they could just as well document this. It's stable and useful and by no means obscure or likely to change.

Comment: @Tomalak I guess it's undocumented because it's technically an improper usage of the `attr` method which is supposed to set content attributes (and `text`, `mouseover`, `css` aren't content attributes). jQuery had a similar situation with the old `attr` method when it introduced `prop` - the functionality of `attr` (rightfully) changed which caused existing code to break for some people. Instead of documenting this, it would be more proper to define a new method for this functionality (for instance, `set`).